# After changing the __init__ class function code, not allow to "get source code" anymore

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, metaclass

I create a meta class that add args and kwargs in `__init__` function parameters from inherited class then supercharge them for init inherited class instance 
Example :

```py
class A():
    def __init__(self, a:int, taunt = None):
        #print('init a')
        self.a = a
        self.test = None

class B(A, metaclass=MagicMeta):
    def __init__(self, b:int):
        #print('init b')
        self.b = b

class Foo(B,metaclass=MagicMeta):
    def __init__(self,yolo, name ='empty', surname = None):
        self.name = name
        self.surname= surname
        #print(self.test)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.__class__) + ": " + str(self.__dict__)

x =Foo(yolo=1,a=2,b=3, name='name!')
print(x.a)
print(x.b)
print(x.name)
print(str(x))
print(inspect.getsourcelines(A.__init__))
inspect.getsourcelines(Foo.__init__)

> 2
> 3
> name!
> "<class '__main__.Foo'>: {}"
> (['    def __init__(self, a:int, taunt = None):\n', "        print('init a')\n", '        self.a = a\n', '        self.test = None\n'], 2)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      4 print(x.name)
      5 print(str(x))
----> 6 inspect.getsourcelines(Foo.__init__)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/inspect.py in getsourcelines(object)
    965     raised if the source code cannot be retrieved."""
    966     object = unwrap(object)
--> 967     lines, lnum = findsource(object)
    968 
    969     if istraceback(object):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/inspect.py in findsource(object)
    796         lines = linecache.getlines(file)
    797     if not lines:
--> 798         raise OSError('could not get source code')
    799 
    800     if ismodule(object):

OSError: could not get source code
```

first problem, the `self` from Foo instance shouldn't be empty, and after changing the code of the `__init__` Foo class function , I'm not allow to read it anymore

Here the MagicMeta code :

```py
import re
from inspect import Parameter

# get arg and kwargs of a function
def get_args(f):
    args = list()
    kwargs = dict()
    for param in inspect.signature(f).parameters.values():
        if (param.kind == param.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD):
            if param.default ==Parameter.empty:
                args.append(param.name)
            else:
                kwargs[param.name]= param.default 
    return args, kwargs 

def  compileKwargs(dct):
    string =""
    poke = False
    for k, o  in dct.items():
        if type(o) == str:
            string+= k+"='"+o+"', "
        else:           
            string+= k+"="+str(o)+", "

    return string

def stringArgs(liste):
    return " ".join([e+"," for e in liste])

def compileArgs(liste1,liste2):
    liste1.extend([e for e in liste2 if e not in liste1])
    return liste1

def editFuncName(actual: str, replace:str):
    #print('EDITFUNCNAME')
    #print(actual)
    string = re.sub('(?<=def ).*?(?=\()',replace, actual)
    #print('string', string)
    return string

import inspect
from textwrap import dedent, indent
# indent the string code
def processCode(code : list):
    string=""
    #print('processcode')
    for i,e  in enumerate(code):
        #print('row', e)
        #print('dedent', e)
        if i != 0:
            string+=indent(dedent(e),'\t')
        else :
            string+=dedent(e)
    return string

import types
class MagicMeta(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        
        setattr(cls,'_CODE_', dict())
        func = cls.__init__
        cls._CODE_[func.__name__]= inspect.getsourcelines(func)
        args2 =get_args(cls.__bases__[0].__init__)
        
        setattr(cls,'_ARGS_', dict())
        cls._ARGS_[func.__name__]=[get_args(func), args2]

        lines = cls._CODE_['__init__']
        string= lines[0][0]
        
        arg, kwarg = cls._ARGS_['__init__'][0]
        arg2, kwarg2 = cls._ARGS_['__init__'][1]
        
        comparg = stringArgs(compileArgs(arg, arg2))

        dct = {**kwarg ,**kwarg2}
        #print(dct)
        newargs = comparg + compileKwargs(dct)
        string = re.sub('(?<=\().*?(?=\))',newargs, string)

        superarg =stringArgs(arg2) + compileKwargs(kwarg2)
        #print(superarg)
        superx = "super({},self).{}({})\n".format(cls.__name__, func.__name__, superarg)

        code = lines[0]
        #print('LINE DEF', code[0])
        code[0]= editFuncName(string, 'tempo')
        code.insert(1, superx)
 
        #print('code:',code)
        codestr  = processCode(code)
        #print('précompile', codestr)
        comp = compile(codestr, '<string>','exec')
        #print(comp)
        
        #exec the code to define the 'tempo' function which will replace __init__
        exec(comp)
        cls.__init__ = types.MethodType(eval('tempo'), cls)
        #print(eval('tempo.__code__'))
```

Comment: This could be an XY problem. Even if you get past your current problem I can see other (possible) problems in the code. For instance, I would expect the `super()` you are adding to be buggy. The init function you are creating is referencing a class by a name that will not be available in the scope of the generated init function. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I try to pass arg from inherited class, which allow me to init the inherited class instance from the last class in the inheritance, it's like inheritance in go with structure.
When I will update a class, every class who inherite this class will be able to init it without change the code of each class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getsourcelines` does not magically de-compiles and reverse engineer the passed in function to recreate source lines that would compile back to an equivalent object.

What it does is to check the attributes in the passed in function and its module, to *retrieve* the actual text, inside the source , physical, file (usually a ".py" file), and get the annotations in the bytecode itself to get to the actual line numbers.

If you as simply as run some code just using the compiled `.pyc` file, removing the source `.py` from the folder, it will fail the same way.

In your case, the source code for the `.__init__` function is not on a file, it is on a dynamically built string, that does not even exist anymore after the `__init__` method in the metaclass exits.

Bu t it is fixable - you just have to persist the strings you use to generate your `__init__` method as a file, and add the path to that file in the process of compiling that string.

If you pass `exec` a string, like you do, it won't work - but if you call `compile` with your string, to create a code object before calling exec, the `compile` call can take a `filename` (actually a path) parameter - that will get embedded in the code object as being the source file. Then you can call `exec` like you do, but pass it the return of `compile` not the source-code string.

As long as that file exists on disk, `getsourcelines()` will return you its contents at the proper offsets.

```py
In [xxx]: import inspect
...

In [104]: bla = "def bla(): return 1"                                                                         

In [105]: open("testx.py", "wt").write(bla)                                                                   
Out[105]: 19

In [106]: b = compile(bla, "testx.py", "exec")                                                                

In [107]: exec(b)                                                                                             

In [108]: bla()                                                                                               
Out[108]: 1

In [109]: inspect.getsourcelines(bla)                                                                         
Out[109]: (['def bla(): return 1\n'], 1)

In [110]: !rm testx.py                                                                                        

In [111]: inspect.getsourcelines(bla)                                                                         
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-111-3459b1636cc6> in <module>
----> 1 inspect.getsourcelines(bla)
[...]

OSError: could not get source code
```

Comment: Depending on what source is wanted, you could also use `functools.wraps` to decorate the generated `__init__`. This means `getsourcelines()` will follow the `__wrapped__` attribute and fetch the source for the original `__init__` rather than the generated `__init__`.

Comment: The second solution suit better for me, but I was not able to develop it correctly,
I update the line `cls.__init__ = functools.wraps(types.MethodType(eval('tempo'), cls)) but get this error :
`TypeError: update_wrapper() got multiple values for argument 'wrapped'`` after init an instance of Foo

Comment: There is no need for calling "MethodType" to assign a method - just assign the function object to the class, like in `cls.__init__ = tempo` . Other tan that, the "tempo"  variable is being created as a global variable by your call to "exec" - you could do better by passing a global dictionary to exec so that it lives there instead. Other than that I did not parse your metaclass line by line - it is a bit convoluted. Dealing with code as strings and using eval is not the best approach to this at all - a proper decorator can . deal with handling the extra parameters.That would imply in a rewrite

Comment: Okey I see what you, but I have to use `eval` as before `exec`, tempo doesn't exist, so I got an error because tempo is not define .
And I have to use `MethodType` otherwise I got a TypeError.
I used your first solution but I keep the problem of the `self`instance empty when I print it.
Should reopen a question or could you give me a quick answer here  ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an XY problem. The problem you are trying to accomplish is more easily solved using the  [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) module or keyword arguments if you are using an older version of Python than 3.7.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class A:
    a: int = 0

@dataclass
class B(A):
    b: int = 1

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.c = self.a + self.b

from dataclasses import field
from typing import List
@dataclass
class C(B):
    foo: List[int] = field(default_factory=list)

# __repr__ is thrown in for free
assert str(C(a=2, b=3, foo=[1, 2, 3])) == 'C(a=2, b=3, foo=[1, 2, 3])'
# retain default args
assert C().a == 0
# using positional args and post_init
assert C(2, 3).c == 5
# mutable defaults
assert C().foo == [] and C().foo is not C().foo
```

With kwargs, you use named arguments to pop off the arguments you need for each class and then pass the rest of the kwargs to the parent classes init function eg.

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, a: int = 0):
        self.a = a

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, *, b:int, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.b = b

class C(B):
    def __init__(self, *, c: int = 2, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.c = c

obj = C(a=1, b=2, c=3)
assert vars(obj) == dict(a=1, b=2, c=3)

# retain defaults
obj2 = C(b=2)
assert obj2.a == 0
```